# Singleton class can get Parameters?

Tags: c#

I would like to relate a singleton class member to existing values. Is it a conflict to the singleton idea?
For example:

```
 class Point
  {
 private int x;
 private int y;
  }
```

I want the singleton instance to be related to the values of Point instance

```
class PointSingleton    //This is the singleton class
{
    private static PointSingleton item;  
    private Point point; //How to relate this member to an existing point values? 

    static PointSingleton()  //Static Ctor to initialize the item instance
    {
        item = new p();
    }
    private p()//private Ctor
    {

    }

    public static PointSingleton GetPointSingleton()// method that enable access to item
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Accessing from another class probably should looks like:

```
     PointSingleton instance = PointSingleton.GetPointSingleton();
```

But where can I insert the wanted values?
Thanks.

Comment: In the static constructor.  If you don't have the info at that point, or it has to change later, you probably shouldn't be using a singleton in the first place.

Comment: Maybe you can add method to PointSingleton called "change coordinates" which will change coordinates some time after?

Comment: Do you mean I might invoke it like that: PointSingleton instance=PointSinleton.GetPointSingleton(); and then : instance.ChangeCoordinates(Point point); ?

Comment: I agree with @cHao that if you can't instantiate the singleton with the values, chances are that it isn't a singleton you should be using but seems much more just like a static method.

Comment: Why can't the point object be static too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit the Point.x and Point.y, simply add a public change method to the PointSingleton

```
class PointSingleton
{
   ...
   public static UpdatePointValues(int x, int y)
   {
      point.x = x;
      point.y = y;
   }
}
```

This will change the values of the underlying Point for all users of the PointSingleTon class. You might also want a public get property to get the Point from the PointSingleton.